# Spectral sequences associated to cohomologies of simplicial type and derived-functor type: Proof of convergence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

Assume I have two cohomology theories $\mathrm{\tilde{H}^{*}}$ and $\mathrm{H^{*}}$, the latter being defined over a Grothendieck site $X$ as the derived functor of some left-exact covariant functor $\mathcal{F}$, and the former being defined in such a way that it generalizes simplicial cohomology when applied to the site of open immersions of a topological space. I do not know whether or not $\mathrm{\tilde{H}}$ can be defined as a derivative of some functor.

I have a spectral sequence
$$\mathrm{E^{p,q}_{2}}=\mathrm{\tilde{H}^{p}}(\mathrm{X},\mathrm{H^{q}}(\mathrm{X},\mathcal{F}))$$

and I want to prove its convergence. So far I have only seen proofs of convergence for spectral sequences of this type where ***both*** cohomologies are derived-functor cohomologies (as a special case of the Grothendieck spectral sequence) or of topological type (via the spectral sequence arising from a filtered graded complex). $\mathrm{\tilde{H}}$ does however satisfy the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms when applied to the Grothendieck site of open subsets of a topological space. Does that alone suffice to prove convergence of the spectral sequence?